# Why is the reputation page not showing + or - reputation points for this question?

Tags: bug, reputation

On seeing @Glorfindel's Reputation page, there is no reputation change for the highlighted question.

[image]

First I thought it might have been undownvoted, but it says **upvote**. But there is no +5 corresponding to it.
Yesterday Glorfindel earned 245 reputation points according to the Reputation page.

This +245 doesn't include that upvote.

Comment: Reputation cap maybe?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks but I still have a doubt.There are  + 70  points after the question has been upvoted, when we see the times they're upvoted.

Comment: Maybe something was deleted at around 23:00, that could remove some earlier votes allowing the later votes to count.